# OpenCV build on windows run on linux

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm a complete newbie with C++, but have to use it for my study project.
What I need is to set things up to code in VS on Windows and generate some sort of executable to run it on Linux, more specifically on RaspberryPI 4 (64-bit).

The project will use OpenCV and YOLO libraries (i'm focusing on OpenCV for now), but I cannot find a proper description about how to set things up in VS so that it finds all the libraries it needs.

I was able to create a working exe file for Windows, but it seems more complicated for Linux. Do I really need to build the entire library (if so, how to do that on Win for Linux)? Maybe there is a more or less detailed description for newbie like me to set things up?

Comment: Search for "cross compile" - this is the term describing the procedure of producing binaries for one platform from another. In some cases it may take significantly more effort than developing natively on the deploy target platform, though.

Comment: It may be easier to use WSL and compile under ubuntu on windows 10 or greater

Comment: drescherjm, kotatsuyaki thanks will try!

Comment: Probably easiest to use wsl or docker to build it on Linux instead of trying to cross compile

Comment: @DanMašek Clumsy me. I meant it is 64 bit.

Comment: I've done something similar and the end result was to write the code in Windows, then compile OpenCV libraries for target device (ARM in your case), then using cmake build for the target device.

Comment: @ZWang if you have some refs or something about how to set things up for this it would be helpful for me.
Right now I managed to set up remote connection from VS 2022 to Rapberry and launch a Hello World app this way. But the target device still fails when I try to compile anything with OpenCV dependencies.

Comment: @Zmur I was working with RKNN package, they have a Cmake file you should have a look at https://github.com/rockchip-linux/rknpu2/blob/master/examples/rknn_common_test/CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @ZWang many thanks! This is interesting.